# How Can I get my div to go back to its original background color on the second click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass, removeclass

I am using the jquery addClass and removeClass animate feature.

What I am doing is when the link is the clicked... the dropdown nav will appear... it is for a responsive site... but all that is working. However What happens is... When the link is clicked on the div class changes and the link class changes.. this is working

however when the link is now clicked on for a second time... i want both classes to revert back to the default classes that they where

this is my code:

```
<div class="display-menu">
<div class="container">
<a id="displaymenu" class="click" style="color:#ffffff;" href="javascript:slideToggle();">In This Section</a>
<script>
    $("a.click").click(function(){
        $("div.display-menu").removeClass("display-menu").addClass("display-menu1");
        $("a.click").removeClass("click").addClass("current");
    });
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Has anyone got any ideas for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added id to top div and changed code to be reliable on element ids

```
<div class="display-menu" id="displaydiv">
    <div class="container">
        <a id="displaymenu" class="click" style="color:#ffffff;" href="javascript:slideToggle();">In This Section</a>
        <script>
            $("a.click").click(function(){
                $("div#displaydiv").toggleClass("display-menu display-menu1");
                $("a#displaymenu").toggleClass("click current");
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe there is a flaw in this approach as on the second click div.display-menu and a.click will not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Try with `toggleClass`

```
    $("div.display-menu").toggleClass("display-menu").toggleClass("display-menu1");
    $("a.click").toggleClass("click").toggleClass("current");
```

Comment: toggleClass can handle more than one class so no need to call them twice on each line.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are changing the classes you will be better off using id's as your selectors and, like the others said, use toggle class.

Otherwise the selections within the handler will not work on the second click.

```
<div id="display-menu-div" class="display-menu">

$("#displaymenu").click(function(){
    $("#display-menu-div").toggleClass("display-menu display-menu1");
    $("#displaymenu").toggleClass("click current");
});
```